# React Script/Start Issues

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with my React application. I JUST created it and when I went to do the first `npm start`, it said

> npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\coding-projects\expense-tracker\package.json'

I found out that it was missing the start script for some reason so I added that in. Then the start started loading up and I got another error message

> Could not find a required file.
> Name: index.html
> Searched in: C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\coding-projects\expense-tracker\public

I have an index.html file so I am unsure why this isn't working and why I am having so many issues all of a sudden. I am using VSCODE and here is the github link for the project I am currently creating https://github.com/AmandaTodero3/expense-tracker

Comment: cd to `expense-tracker` and then execute command?

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned your repository, moved everything from `expense-tracker/expense-tracker/` to `expense-tracker/`, deleted the empty, unnecessary directory `expense-tracker/expense-tracker` and line 1 in `expense-tracker/src/App.js` (because it referred to a file `./logo.svg`, which didn't exist), ran `npm start` and it's working just fine (shows "Hello World!").

Comment: Thank you all of the files are moving right now. Hoping this works!